# create NSString UTF8/Unicode character from int >127

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I want to create characters from int values which are >127.

For example: I calculate 133 and I want the character Å 
Or I calculate 149 and I want character Õ

(see http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec)

I I use the following code, it does not return the correct character:

```
int pos = 133;    
NSString *TF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", pos];
```

this is because the int >127 so it is no regular ASCII (which can be done with %c)

Also %C does not work.

Do I need some encoding? Or a different operator in the `stringWithFormat`?
I have looked at `CFString` class, but I don't understand how I can use it here and if it is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

What encoding are you using where 133 encoded the character Å?

From the site

```
Unicode                UTF-8
code point  character  (dec.)   name
U+00C5      Å          195 133  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE
```

133 is not a valid value, the value you want is: 195 133 (two bytes). UTF8 is only one byte for characters up to 127.

```
char utf8[2] = {195, 133};
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8];
NSLog(@"s: '%@'", s);
```

NSLog output:

> s: 'Å'

The code point from the web page is U+00C5, using UTF32:

```
u_int32_t bytes = 0x00C5;
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&bytes length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"s: '%@'", s);
```

NSLog output:

> s: 'Å'

Comment: Not yet any encoding, nothing works. Now with NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding, the 133 works! But now, when I test it with 154, I creates the character Ü, but I need Ú. So strange.... And the examples I use are from the website for the UTF8 data...

Comment: There is always an encoding. An encoding specifies the character associated with a value. Values above 127 (decimal) are not standard ASCII and thus non standard, the characters vary based on platform whim. What is the link to the website? Why are you specifying characters with decimal numbers above 127? If you must use a Unicode code point.

Comment: For the URL: check the link in the original post: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec. And if I can translate the int to a Unicode value to a String character, that would be perfect as well! But how do I do that?

Comment: From that site 133 is not a valid value, the value you want is: 195 133. UTF8 is only one byte for characters up to 127. See updated answer.

Comment: Finaly, it works! The trick is not to use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", pos]; but [NSString appendFormat:@"%c", pos]; The only problem is with 0. The character for U+0000 is nog working. Any suggestions?